# MySQL swap primary key values

Tags: mysql

The accepted answer to [sql swap primary key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810606/sql-swap-primary-key-values) fails with the error `Can't reopen table: 't'` - presumably this has something to do with opening the same table for writing twice, causing a lock.

Is there any shortcut, or do I have to get both, set one of them to `NULL`, set the second one to the first one, then set the first one to the previously fetched value of the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To swap id values of 1 and 2, I would use a SQL statement like this:

**EDIT :** this does NOT work on an InnoDB table, only works on a MyISAM table, per my testing.

```
UPDATE mytable a 
  JOIN mytable b ON a.id = 1 AND b.id = 2 
  JOIN mytable c ON c.id = a.id
   SET a.id = 0
     , b.id = 1
     , c.id = 2
```

For this statement to work, the id value of 0 must not exist in the table, any unused value would be suitable... but to get this to work in a single SQL statement, you need to (temporarily) use a third id value.

---

This solution works for regular MyISAM tables, not temporary tables. I missed that this was being performed on a temporary table, I was confused by the error message you reported `Can't reopen table:`.

To swap id values 1 and 2 in a temporary table, I'd run three separate statements, again, using a temporary placeholder value of 0:

```
UPDATE mytable a SET a.id = 0 WHERE a.id = 1;
UPDATE mytable b SET b.id = 1 WHERE b.id = 2;
UPDATE mytable c SET c.id = 2 WHERE c.id = 0;
```

Edit: Fixed errors

Comment: @Kolink: I tested on an InnoDB table, and you are correct. The statement does work on a MyISAM table. I'd recommend the three statement approach, that should work on MyISAM, InnoDB and temporary (also MyISAM) tables. Actually, my testing with InnoDB reveals that 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1, and then 1 gets changed back to 2 again... testing with MyISAM yields a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use temporary tables for this.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html):

> You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.
>   For example, the following does not work:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM temp_table, temp_table AS t2;
ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'temp_table'
```

> This error also occurs if you refer to a temporary table multiple
>   times in a stored function under different aliases, even if the
>   references occur in different statements within the function.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry if I don't get it right, but why does a simple three way exchange not work?

Like this:

```
create table yourTable(id int auto_increment, b int, primary key(id));

insert into yourTable(b) values(1), (2);
select * from yourTable;

DELIMITER $$
create procedure pkswap(IN a int, IN b int)
BEGIN
select @max_id:=max(id) + 1 from yourTable;
update yourTableset id=@max_id where id = a;
update yourTableset id=a where id = b;
update yourTableset id=b where id = @max_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

call pkswap(1, 2);

select * from yourTable;
```

Comment: Who mentioned `TEMPORARY` tables?

Comment: Well, using a non-temporary table, I get the error "duplicate entry for key".

Comment: Well, that's a lot of work to go through when a three way exchange can be done much more easily...

Comment: Please explain your problem a bit more. I don't get it.

Comment: What's a lot of work here? You create the procedure once and call it whenever you need. Plus, this solution is fool prove.

Comment: `select @max_id:=max(id) + 1 from yourTable;` isn't very concurrency-safe.  What happens if a record with that `id` gets inserted before the following `update`?

Comment: Thought that it would be concurrency-safe by putting it in a procedure? This is not the case? Thought a procedure would be treated as one transaction.

Comment: Alternatively and to keep things simple just update it to 0 instead of `max(id)+1` if it's impossible that there are values lower than 1.