# Swap primary keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, swap

I am trying to achieve the same thing as asked in this question [sql swap primary key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810606/sql-swap-primary-key-values) but I can't seem to get it running with newer mysql versions becausue of the error message `Error Code: 1706. Primary key/partition key update is not allowed since the table is updated both as 't' and 't2'.`

My table would look like this

```
id   name
---------
1    john

id   name
---------
2    jim
```

and expected result would look like this

```
id   name
---------
2    john

id   name
---------
1    jim
```

Is there any "one-liner" for that?

Comment: update your question and show the related sql code

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected output on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: done, I copied the example from the answer to the linked question

Comment: Did you try the other answers in the linked question ? Like this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584576/2469308

Comment: I am not even trying because the approach is the same and the error message would be that one of the values is a duplicate. Approach with decode would deliver a message that the parameter count is incorrect.

Comment: Is `id` value changeable to 0 ?

Comment: yes, mysql allows you to use 0 as it is a valid int number

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the easier and safer way to do it is to leave the primary key as it is and swap the values of the other columns, should give you the same results

Comment: It does not work in newer versions of MySQL. check the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810606/sql-swap-primary-key-values#comment15792689_2810789 and that is the whole point of this question.

Comment: This is not the case. Welcome to the community. If that was the  case the error message would state something else not the one I am getting

Comment: Okay^^ I'll change my answer

Comment: This would work for own tables where I got control over. As the tables I am working with do not belong to me I cannot be sure, that the number of the columns doesn't change. I also would need to count on the fact that there are no other uniques or primaries...