# SQLite Swap 2 Primary Key Values In A Column

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, relational-database, primary-key

My table **student** is as follows:

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| Dave | 3414 |
| Bob | 2861 |

The ID is the primary key value that has a unique constraint. I'm trying to swap the two primary key values, so Bob's ID is 3414 and Dave's ID is 2861. What's the quickest way to do this?

```
UPDATE student SET Id=2861 WHERE Id=3414;
UPDATE student SET Id=3414 WHERE Id=2861;
```

These two statements won't work as it will create duplicate primary keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in three steps (Wrapped in a transaction so it's atomic as far as other connections to the database are concerned), by first changing one of the PKs to a value that's not already in the database. Negative numbers work well, assuming your PKs are normally values `>= 0`, which is true of automatically generated `rowid`/`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` values in Sqlite.

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE student SET Id=-Id WHERE Id=2861;
UPDATE student SET Id=2861 WHERE Id=3414;
UPDATE student SET Id=3414 WHERE Id=-2861;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody asked something like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810606/sql-swap-primary-key-values)

but it apparently does not work in some versions

Comment: Yeah I tried it already, didn't seem to work