# SQL swap field values

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a SQL table (MYSQL 4.0 to be precise) composed of the following :

```
int no (primary)
int field1
int field2
```

I would like to swap the values of field1 with the values of field2 and vice-versa.

```
Ex.: 1;2.5;3.76 becomes 1;3.76;2.5
```

I need a swapping temporary variable of some sort. But I don't think I can use something like

```
Set @var1 = field1
```

inside my update statement. And I don't think altering the table to add a temporary column is my best bet either.

Comment: Do you need to do anything other than UPDATE YourTable SET field1=field2, field2=field1

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this to only a subset of the columns? (Otherwise, you could just rename the columns!)

A temporary column seems the easiest, and most straightforward solution to me.

Comment: @mdma : Yes, I need to do something else: it doesn't work. Btw, your comment should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Will : I do need to apply this only to a subset of rows but I like your way to think outside the box. Would have upvoted for that reason if this had been an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this

```
UPDATE swap_test 
SET x=(@temp:=x), 
    x = y, 
    y = @temp
WHERE ...
```

[here](http://beerpla.net/2009/02/17/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/) as solution with session variables (there are other solutions in the provided link and also a link back to another so question)

Comment: @Silence, yes you are right, no point in keeping the multi table version of the answer, the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html clearly states that the behaviour is not defined (although I'll run some tests now out of curiosity)

Comment: Works. Easiest answer to implement. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought was to try this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
   SET field1=field2
      ,field2=field1
   WHERE ...
```

SQL Server syntax here (but has worked this way in every database I've ever used, I've not used mysql):

```
declare @x table (field1 int, field2 int)
insert @x values (1,2)
update @x set field1=field2, field2=field1
select * from @x
```

OUTPUT

```
field1      field2
----------- -----------
2           1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

However after a little research, I came across this: [Swapping column values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/559291#559291)

Comment: This will not work as expected in mysql, there's a overview of UPDATE behaviours in one of the so questions, mysql and ather DBMS fail on this

Comment: @Unreason, works fine in SQL Srver, but see the link in my edited answer.

Comment: @KM, It works in oracle, postgres, db2 and I think SQLite as expected. It was mysql and another one failing... can't find the question now.

Comment: Ok, found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203202/sql-update-order-of-evaluation

Comment: @Silence said `After testing it: doesn't work in mysql`. Duh, I said that the code was for SQL Server! The linked answer shows how to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a work table, push the data there and the join with your current table?