# Not sure what is the execution stack of mySql fo my below query

Tags: mysql

So, I am trying to update the status_modified_time only if the status has changed, else keep it the same.

```
UPDATE table SET status = <new_status>, 
status_modified_time = IF(status = <new_status>, status_modified_time, now())  WHERE id = <id>
```

this query makes status_modified_time = status_modified_time

```
UPDATE table SET status = <new_status>, 
status_modified_time = IF(status = <old_status>, status_modified_time, now())  WHERE id = <id>
```

this query makes status_modified_time = now()
is it that mysql is updating the status field first and then checking the condition??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left to right order of evaluation!
[SQL UPDATE order of evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203202/sql-update-order-of-evaluation)

I checked my query by updating the modified_time first.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  The behavior of MySQL is not standard.  SQL isn't supposed to have an order -- everything conceptually is supposed to happen at the same time, so referencing a column in an `UPDATE` query *should* reference the old value... but it doesn't.  It is indeed done left-to-right.