# mysql update column base on calculation of another column

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

mysql 5.7, mybatis 3.4

i have a table `tableA` whose `id` is the pk, `outstanding` is decimal and `status` is int.

in my java code, there are following steps(they are in one transaction):

1. `select * from tableA for update`
2. `update tableA set outstanding = outstanding - #{amount}, status=IF(outstanding = 0, 2, 3) where id=#{id}`

what i want is, e.g. :
if `outstanding` is 10, and the `amount` is 10, then after run the code above, the `outstanding` should be 0, and `status` should be 2(represent full settled); if `amount` is 5,then after run the code above, the `outstanding` should be 5, and `status` should be 3(partial settle).

However, i encounter one time that `outstanding = 0, but status = 3`, this is incorrect.(in most cases, it works, `outstanding = 0, status = 2`).

so is there potential problem for `update tableA set outstanding = outstanding - #{amount}, status=IF(outstanding = 0, 2, 3) where id=#{id}`? if yes, why?

Comment: You should know that MySQL behaves [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2203202/1261766) from the other DBs (or the SQL standard). MySQL doc [states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) that "Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order". The word "generally" seems to imply there is an exception even for a single-table UPDATE.

Comment: @ave Thanks for your hint. For my problem, after checking my code, i thought the most likely reason is this `single table update`, but cannot find the evidence to prove there is an exception even for a single-table update.

Comment: As you select the values with `for update` first (I assume the actual SQL includes `WHERE id = #{id}`), it would be better to calculate the values of `outstanding` and `status` in Java code. This way, the SQL is dead simple `... set outstanding=#{outstanding}, status=#{status}` and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @ave yes, I changed it to `set outstanding=#{outstanding},status=#{status}`. Thanks!